# Update Data From Dynamic Form Using Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent-relationship

I have some problem, but I'm not understand why its not working.

I have a **Quotation.php** model, like :

```
class Quotation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'quotation';

    protected $fillable = [
        'no_quotation',
        'subject',
        'to',
        'qutation_date',
        'expire_date',
        'pickup',
        'destination',
        'via',
        'customer',
        'address',
        'totalcost',
        'subtotal',
        'tax',
        'grandtotal'
    ];
}
```

**Item.php** model, like :

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_quotation',
        'name',
        'qty',
        'cost',
        'totalcost',
        'rate',
        'totalrate'
    ];
}
```

**TermCondition.php** model, like :

```
class TermCondition extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'term_and_condition';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_quotation',
        'caption'
    ];
}
```

and **QuotationController.php** like :

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $quotation = Quotation::findOrFail($request->id);
    $quotation->no_quotation    = $request->no_quotation;
    $quotation->subject         = $request->subject;
    $quotation->quotation_date  = $request->quotation_date;
    $quotation->expire_date     = $request->expire_date;
    $quotation->pickup          = $request->pickup;
    $quotation->destination     = $request->destination;
    $quotation->via             = $request->via;
    $quotation->to              = $request->to;
    $quotation->customer        = $request->customer;
    $quotation->destination     = $request->destination;
    $quotation->address         = $request->address;
    $quotation->totalcost       = $request->totalcost;
    $quotation->subtotal        = $request->subtotal;
    $quotation->tax             = $request->tax;
    $quotation->grandtotal      = $request->grandtotal;
    $quotation->status          = 'SUBMIT';
    $quotation->update();

    $deleteItems = Item::where('id_quotation', $request->id)->delete();
    $deleteTerms = TermCondition::where('id_quotation', $request->id)->delete();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($request->items); $i++) {
        $item = new Item;
        $item->id_quotation = $request->id;
        $item->name         = $request->items[$i]['name'];
        $item->qty          = $request->items[$i]['qty'];
        $item->cost         = $request->items[$i]['cost'];
        $item->totalcost    = $request->items[$i]['totalcost'];
        $item->rate         = $request->items[$i]['rate'];
        $item->totalrate    = $request->items[$i]['totalrate'];
        $item->save();
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($request->terms); $i++) {
        $term               = new TermCondition;
        $term->id_quotation = $request->id;
        $term->caption      = $request->terms[$i]['caption'];
        $term->save();
    }

    return redirect('quotation-show');
}
```

In **routes.php** like :

```
Route::post('/quotation-update/', 'QuotationController@update');
```

And last, I return data at **QuotationController.php** to `Json` like :

```
{
    "_token": "emShldN8ecxrPzV9zhX64IlFk8ZPelPFwCLNd7zl",
    "id": "1",
    "no_quotation": "QUOT/12/12/2020",
    "subject": "Installation Air Conditioner",
    "quotation_date": "2019-12-12",
    "expire_date": "2019-12-26",
    "pickup": "Jakarta",
    "destination": "Bandung",
    "via": "Land - CDD",
    "to": "Helmi Wantono",
    "customer": "PT. EDI Indonesia",
    "address": "Jl. Yos Sudarso Kav 18, Sunter Jaya. Sunter, Jakarta Utara.",
    "items": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Air Conditioner",
            "qty": "2",
            "cost": "2,000",
            "totalcost": "4,000",
            "rate": "2,500",
            "totalrate": "5,000"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Compressor",
            "qty": "2",
            "cost": "1,000",
            "totalcost": "2,000",
            "rate": "1,500",
            "totalrate": "3,000"
        }
    },
    "totalcost": "6,000",
    "subtotal": "8,000",
    "tax": "80",
    "grandtotal": "7,920",
    "terms": {
        "1": {
            "caption": "Price exclude insurance."
        },
        "2": {
            "caption": "Price exclude packing service."
        }
    }
}
```

This code just worked for update **Quotation** information, not for items and terms.
What the best way for this case? Thank you

Comment: Try to use relationship and request() helpers to make your code elegant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to define Relationship between tables.

```
//QUOTATION Model
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}

public function terms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TermCondition');
}

//ITEM Model
public function quotation()
{  

   return $this- belongsTo('App\Quotation','id_quotation');
 }

//TermCondition Model
public function quotation()
{  

   return $this- belongsTo('App\Quotation','id_quotation');
 }
```

Now in your controller when you you successfully update the quotation then update the rested of the other table.

```
public function update(Request $request) {
$quotation = Quotation::findOrFail($request->id);
$quotation->no_quotation    = $request->no_quotation;
...
if($quotation->update()) {

  $getQuotationID = $quotation->id;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= count($request->items); $i++) {
    $item = Item::where('id_quotation', $getQuotationID)->first();
    $item->id_quotation = $getQuotationID;
    ...
    $item->totalrate    = $request->items[$i]['totalrate'];
    $item->save();
  };

  for ($i = 1; $i <= count($request->terms); $i++) {
    $term = TermCondition::where('id_quotation', $getQuotationID)->first();
    $term->id_quotation = $getQuotationID;
    $term->caption      = $request->terms[$i]['caption'];
    $term->save();
  };

return redirect('quotation-show');
};
```

Comment: Try to update your looping. but I'm not sure how your data are coming from the form. `if ($it = $request->get('items')) {
    foreach($it as $i) { // Update logic goes here for item }`. And do the same thing for Term Condition. Also try to set your $i to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: thank you for answer, I found the wrong code at input name form input of array and then return error offset. I loop at form update `name="item[$i][index]"`, but at the dynamic form I write `name="items[$i][index]"`

Comment: I'm so  happy that you figured that little mistake out.